# How to return to previous value with Aframe component?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I wrote a component for **Aframe** to change the **src** and the **scale** of an image when the cursor is hover it. Then, when it exit, I want to return to default value.

So, I store the default src and the default scale values, then update it with **setAttribute**
When the cursor go out, it return to default src, but not to default scale.

How to do that properly?

Here is my component :

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('change-hotspots-on-hover', {
    schema: {
        src: {default: '#hotspots'},
        scale: {type: 'vec3', default: {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}},
    },

    init: function () {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;
        var defaultSrc = el.getAttribute('src');
        var defaultScale = el.getAttribute('scale');

        console.log("Init");

        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (){
            console.log("Enter");

            el.setAttribute('src', data.src);
            setTimeout(() => { 
                el.setAttribute('scale', data.scale);
            }, 1);
        });

        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (){
            console.log("Exit");

            el.setAttribute('src', defaultSrc);
            el.setAttribute('scale', defaultScale);
        });
    }
});
```

And my image:

```
<a-image position="-10 4 -10" scale="1 1 1" material="" src="#hotspot" 
change-hotspots-on-hover="src: #hotspot_hover; scale: 7 3 2;"></a-image>
```

Comment: which mouse event didn't work properly? 
"mouseleave" or "mouseenter" ?

Comment: Both work properly: src and scale change with mouseenter, Src change with mouseleave but not scale. The problem seems to come from the var defaultScale wich is overwritten after the mouseenter. 
I tried to consol.log it and it's not the same after that.

Comment: please test this: use "const" or "let" instead of your variable declaration with "var"

Comment: Don't work. Nothing change :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.2.0/src/core/a-entity.js#L780) `getAttribute('scale')` returns the scale reference, not a copy - meaning if you change the scale later on (hovering) - the object that `defaultScale` refers to is actually the one being changed.

You can check that with a log in your `mouseover` listener:

```
console.log(defaultScale) // here are the default scale values
el.setAttribute('scale', data.scale);
console.log(defaultScale) // here are the data.scale values
```

You can work it around with, for example, stringifying the default scale, thus turning it into a simple "1 1 1"(provided its the default):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('change-hotspots-on-hover', {
      schema: {
        src: {default: '#source'},
        scale: {type: 'vec3', default: "1 1 1"},
      },
      init: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;
          var defaultSrc = el.getAttribute('src');
          var defaultScale = AFRAME.utils.coordinates.stringify(el.getAttribute('scale'));
          el.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
            el.setAttribute('src', data.src);
            setTimeout(() => {
              el.setAttribute('scale', data.scale);
            }, 1);
          });

          el.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
            el.setAttribute('src', defaultSrc);
            el.setAttribute('scale', defaultScale);
          });
      }
    });
  </script>
  <a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
    <a-assets>
      <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpeg">
    </a-assets>
    <a-box position="0 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" change-hotspots-on-hover="src: #image; scale: 2 2 2"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
```